# OpenCV Android: Hand detection

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV in android. I'm a total beginner in OpenCV. My end goal is to recognize hand gestures. But for this, I first have to detect a human hand. I don't know where to start. Any help?

**EDIT** I have already imported OpenCV and successfully ran 2 sample projects. The face detector sample didn't work though. Now I wanna proceed to detect hand gestures. Only 4 gestures: when a user moves his hand from left to right in front of camera, same for three more directions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are planning to detect only 4 motions, hence you simplify your task to a huge degree.

Go through these links [1](http://simena86.github.io/blog/2013/08/12/hand-tracking-and-recognition-with-opencv/) [2](http://www.intorobotics.com/9-opencv-tutorials-hand-gesture-detection-recognition/) and get yourself acquainted with basics of hand detection.

Your main aim should be to detect the hand from background, something like shown in the image below.

[image: hand]

Once that is done, you can keep taking images in succession and process it and keep track of center and end points of the hand.

Now by simply subtracting these points of the successive image, you can easily find the possible 4 directions the hand can move in your case.

Comment: Well, the approach seems pretty good. I'm gonna work on it now.

Comment: But what I need is some starting code to play around with.

Comment: I understand, but i think what you are looking for is really simple. Just google around and try some codes which you think should work. Its a learning process so efforts will teach you.

Comment: Hi @SalmanYounas, I'm currently working on a similar problem. Do you have any leads on hand gesture detection with opencv on android?